# Could not find implicit value for parameter write eror, yet I defined the handler using the macro

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I have the following:

Account.scala

```
package modules.accounts

import java.time.Instant
import reactivemongo.api.bson._

case class Account(id: String, name: String)

object Account {
  type ID = String

  implicit val accountHandler: BSONDocumentHandler[Account] = Macros.handler[Account]

//   implicit def accountWriter: BSONDocumentWriter[Account] = Macros.writer[Account]
//   implicit def accountReader: BSONDocumentReader[Account] = Macros.reader[Account]
}
```

AccountRepo.scala

```
package modules.accounts

import java.time.Instant
import reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

final class AccountRepo(
    val coll: BSONCollection
)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
  import Account.{ accountHandler, ID }

  def insertTest() = {
    val doc = Account(s"account123", "accountName") //, Instant.now)
    coll.insert.one(doc)
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter writer: AccountRepo.this.coll.pack.Writer[modules.accounts.Account]
[error]     coll.insert.one(doc)
```

From what I understand the implicit handler that is generated by the macro should be enough and create the Writer.   What am I doing wrong?

Reference: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/bson/typeclasses.html

Comment: It looks like the compiler cannot find a `Writer[_]`, probably the macro code needs that `Writer` in scope to build a `BSONDocumentHandler[Account]`. Make sure you have a `AccountRepo.this.coll.pack.Writer[modules.accounts.Account]` in scope when calling that macro.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code seems to compile https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jILAbk8nSNGQgIIC2lHcpw Probably you haven't provided the whole code (minimal reproducible example).

Comment: The code compiles fine. If you are getting this error when running within Intellij, it might be due to outdated or conflicting compiled files (which happens due to some bug in intellij plugin), then delete your target folders and let intellij recomiple everything from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is mismixing different versions.

The macro generated handler is using the new BSON API, as it can be seen with the import `reactivemongo.api.bson`, whereas the collection is using an old driver, as it can be seen as it uses `reactivemongo.api.collections.bson` instead of `reactivemongo.api.bson.collection`.

It's recommended to have a look at the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/release-details.html#bson-library), and not mixing incompatible versions of related libraries.